# Assign taken Image to ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers. `ViewControllerA` and `ViewcontrollerB`.`ViewControllerA` has a button which takes you `ViewControllerB` through segue.

`ViewControllerB` allows user to take picture via device Camera and should assign this image in `ViewcontrollerA`. But my app crashes.

**ViewControllerA**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *userPicture;
```

**ViewControllerB**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    ViewControllerA *userPhoto=[[ViewControllerA alloc] init];

    userPhoto.userPicture.image=chosenImage;


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

It allows to `Use Photo` button and app crashes when it assigns taken image.
Getting the following error message:

> [ViewControllerB userPicture]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x14e636160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly initializing another `ViewControllerA` object in this line:

```
ViewControllerA *userPhoto=[[ViewControllerA alloc] init];
```

You should implement delegate pattern instead. Create a protocol `ViewControllerBDelegate` and a method `- (void)imageSelected:(UIImage *)iImage` into it.

Set your `ViewControllerA`  as delegate to ViewControllerB in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method and then implement the above delegate method  method in `ViewControllerA`. From `ViewControllerB` simply call `[self.delegate imageSelected: chosenImage]`.

**EDIT:** Code example per OP request:

**Step 1:** Add following protocol to your `ViewControllerB.h`

```
@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)imageSelected:(UIImage *)iImage;

@end
```

**Step 2:** Add delegate property to your `ViewControllerB.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
```

**Step 3:** Implement below method in your `ViewControllerA.m`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)iSegue sender:(id)iSender {
    ViewControllerB *vcontrollerB = (ViewControllerB *)iSender.destinationViewController;
    vcontrollerB.delegate = self;
}
```

**Step 4:** Implement below method in your `ViewControllerB.m`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageSelected:)]) {
            [self.delegate imageSelected:chosenImage];
        }
    }];
}
```

**Step 5:** Implement below method in your `ViewControllerA.m`

```
- (void)imageSelected:(UIImage *)iImage {
    self.userPicture.image = iImage;
}
```

As a side note, I would rather put `userPicture` image view in my implementation file if it is not required to be accessed from outside `ViewControllerA`.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, it seems your answer is right, could you please elaborate by giving code example?

Comment: Hi Andrea, Abhinav is right here. Suggestion of Abhinav is the correct solution. You can use this reference to use delegates in your app: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Anubhav, I have implemented each step but for some reason it does not call delegate method in ViewcontrollerA, therefore it is not assigning the taken image.

Comment: I am sure there would be some small object issue only. Would it be possible for you to share your code on github link so I could take a look and suggest you the fix. On a lighter note my name is Abhinav :). @AndreaBanderas

Comment: Can you please put a break point on `prepareForSegue` and check if assignment is happening. Also put a break point inside your `imagePickerController:` to check if completion block is being called and that `self.delegate` is not nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90284/discussion-between-abhinav-and-andrea-banderas).

Comment: It works like a charm. There is only one small correction. `completion^ ` --> `completion:^`

Comment: Yeah just did - missed in a rush to type :). Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: One small question, I am getting a warning in the following line `vcontrollerB.delegate = self;` how could I able to fix it? The warning message says `Assigning to id < ViewControllerBDelegate > from incompatible ViewcontrollerA`

Comment: To fix that u need conform ViewControllerA to ViewControllerBDelegate. Just add <ViewControllerBDelegate> next to your interface declaration in ViewControllerA.h class.